# Angular 2: Nested *ngFor JSON data

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have some JSON data structured as:

```
[{"x":"Example1", "y":["1","2","3"],"id":"one"},{"x":"Example2", "y":["11","12","13"],"id":"two"}]
```

I am trying to bind the data so it shows:

**One**

*1* *2* *3*

**Two**

*11* *12* *13*

I'm pretty sure I'm doing this entirely wrong, but can't seem to get my head around it...! I can get a result using `{{item.y[0]}}`, but can't do this nested `*ngFor`.

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of Data">
    <h2>{{item.id}}</h2>
    <h3 *ngFor="let y of item">{{item.y}}</h3>
  </ion-item>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is the following:

```
<h3 *ngFor="let y of item.y">{{y}}</h3>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of Data">
    <h2>{{item.id}}</h2>
    <h3 *ngFor="let y of item.y">{{y}}</h3>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.